# Infinite Recursion in Java?

Tags: java

Obviously the following recursion in Java will cause stack overflow error:

```
public class XXX {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        main(null);
    }
}
```

But what if I catch this error and invoke the function again?

```
public class XXX {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            main(null);
        } catch(StackOverflowError E) {
            main(null);
        }
    }
}
```

how does it perform then??

Comment: Why don't you try that?

Comment: Let us know what's the result

Comment: Well I did try it, multiple times, and it just gave me infinite recursion..

Comment: But is this actually permitted in a real program?

Comment: @BoWang Why wouldn't it be? You'd still be throwing `StackOverflowException`s until you used up all your available heap memory, I imagine.

Comment: Isn't yours a real program?

Comment: Hmmmm dunno. but since it throws error i feel that there are some restrictions in this type of recursion.

Comment: Actually, this wouldn't work. Because the second invocation inside the `try/catch` isn't `try/catch`'d. ;)

Comment: @AlexT. It is caught, but one level higher in the stack, it will eventually end but if the stack allows `n` calls I think this will do `2^n` calls before the top level call to main inside the top-level catch finally throws and causes the program to exit.

Comment: I don't know this, nor do I have any evidence of this, but I'm imagining that if one were to perform such an obvious abuse of programming practice, then the result would be platform specific.

Comment: lol "abuse" is so precise

Comment: @BoWang I would recommend doing some reading about why `Error`s shouldn't be caught

Comment: Here's an example of a platform specific problem that could occur. Since your program is going to be starved of memory over and over, it could create a problem in the system thread where eventually it can't perform some critical function due to all the available memory being wiped out. Then at some unpredictable interval, the error could be something other than the StackOverflowError. I am just speculating because I don't know how strict the JVM is at specifying that type of implementation detail. In short, catching StackOverflowError is almost always a bad idea.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because you can just run this code and find out yourself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The program will eventually stop because the call to `main(null)` in `catch` block doesn't again catch `StackOverflowError`. The `StackOverflowError` will eventually propagate down the stack.

You can see it by decreasing the stack size with `-Xss108k` JVM option (lowest possible value on my JVM) and changing the program to allocate as much as possible on the stack e.g. using local `double` variables:

```
public static void main(String... args) {
  try {
    double a00 = 0.13;
    double a01 = 0.13;
    ...
    double a99 = 0.13;
    double b00 = 0.13;
    double b01 = 0.13;
    ...
    double k99 = 0.13;

    main(null);
  } catch (StackOverflowError ex) {
    main(null);
  }
}
```

This causes `StackOverflowError` to be thrown after just 5 recursive calls and the program exits.

Comment: It doesn't make as much sense as an infinite loop and is not a good idea. If `main` called anything else which might call other methods, it will throw at random points inside `main` on each iteration depending on the depth of the call-stack when that call to `main` started. It will also stop iterating eventually due to the point that @Alex T. noticed, although it will run for a very long time.

Comment: @Paulpro thank you for pointing this out, you are right.

Comment: No problem, nice demonstration of it.